# Is there any way to define own options in *.pc files except standard options

Tags: configuration-files, configure, configurationmanager, pkg-config

I am trying to make a .pc file and want to define a flag `ldflags` and use it something like this

```
pkg-config package --ldflags
```

but it's showing `unknown option ldflags`.
Is there a way to define my own option in pc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.pc file has special format, check [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html#concepts):

> The file format contains predefined metadata keywords and freeform
> variables.

keywords are fixed, e.g. **Cflags** and most of them correspond to pkg-config tool options e.g. *--cflags*. But variables:

> ... can be used by the keyword definitions for flexibility or to store
> data not covered by pkg-config

So, it possible to add own, for example I created minimum possible one (Name, Version, Description are mandatory keywords):

```
$ cat test.pc
Name: test
Version: 1
Description: test
aaa=bbb

$ pkg-config --variable=aaa
bbb
```

It's possible to list all with --print-variables option (interestingly though that *pcfiledir* variable is added automatically):

```
$ pkg-config --print-variables test.pc
aaa
pcfiledir

$ pkg-config --variable=pcfiledir
.
```

It can even (re)define one variable using another:

```
$ cat test.pc
Name: test
Version: 1
Description: test
aaa=bbb${ccc}

$ pkg-config test.pc --variable=aaa --define-variable=ccc=xxx
bbbxxx
```

Wonder about your use case? since contents of this file is just for keeping metadata about dependencies some package has. Maybe you should add instead these flags to **Libs** or **Libs.private** keywords?

Comment: got it, Thanks. Also is there any way to write conditional statements in it.
Like if(${a}==b) then c=...
actually the thing is that I have to write a .pc file for shell scripting file that actually have conditional statements in it.
Thanks

Comment: No, .pc file is not a "script" it's just a little bit more specialized and targeted version of .conf file. I wonder, why isn't it better/possible to have conditionals in shell script file itself?